# Exception thrown: 'System.UnauthorizedAccessException' in HP.HPRM.OfficeIntegration.Outlook.dll Additional information:

Tags: outlook, outlook-addin

I have written an `OutllokAddin`.In my email I have attached one draft email. When I open the email and try to open the attach draft email I got the below error.

Exception thrown:

> 'System.UnauthorizedAccessException' in
>   HP.HPRM.OfficeIntegration.Outlook.dll Additional information: The
>   property
>   "http://schemas.microsoft.com/mapi/string/{00020386-0000-0000-C000-000000000046}/CheckInInfoID"
>   does not support this operation.

below is my code where SetProperty is throwing error.

```
Interop.PropertyAccessor propertyAccessor = null;

try
 {
   propertyAccessor = this.GetPropertyAccessor();
   propertyAccessor.SetProperty(propString, value);
 }
```

I have faced this in office 2016. I believe same is also replicate in office 2019.

When I create a new email I don't see the error. Only if I open the attachment I get the error.

Comment: What is the type of the value variable?

Comment: "http://schemas.microsoft.com/mapi/string/{00020386-0000-0000-C000-000000000046}/CheckInInfoID"-- this one is my value

Comment: That looks like the value of the propString variable. How about the value of the "value" variable?